# Dealing with undefined numbers in definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

While solving this particular definite integral:
$$\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-2ax} dx$$

I could evaluate the indefinite integral as:
$$- \frac{e^{-2ax} (2a^2x^2 + 2ax + 1)}{4a^3}$$

But I fall into this problem of $0 * \infty$ upon putting the limits. What's the correct way to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Note that your antiderivative needs a special case for $a=0$. For $a\ne 0$, that limit depends on the sign of $a$: it's $0$ if $a>0$ and $\infty$ if $a<0$. This is the well-known fact that, for any polynomial $p$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{p(x)}{e^x}=0$.

Comment: Replace the upper limit by $k$ and then take the limit as $k \to \infty$. You can then use l'Hopital.

Comment: For $a \gt 0$ the integrand is positive but your integral is negative.  For $a \lt 0$ it goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and answers, it is clear that you must have $a > 0$ for the integral to converge. Now, if you want to evaluate the integral as you suggest, separate the terms
\begin{align*}
- \frac{e^{-2ax} (2a^2x^2 + 2ax + 1)}{4a^3} \Big|_{0}^{\infty} & = 
\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} - \frac{e^{-2ax} (2a^2x^2 + 2ax + 1)}{4 a^3} \right) + \frac{1}{4a^{3}} \\
& = -\left(\lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{e^{-2ax}2a^2x^2}{4 a^3} + \frac{2e^{-2ax}ax}{{4 a^3} } + \frac{e^{-2ax}}{4 a^3} \right) + \frac{1}{4a^{3}} \\
& = -\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2 e^{2ax}a} + \frac{x}{{2e^{2ax} a^2} } + \frac{1}{4e^{2ax} a^3} \right) + \frac{1}{4a^{3}} \\
& = -(0 +0 + 0) + \frac{1}{4a^3} \\
& = \frac{1}{4a^3}
\end{align*}
in other case you cand use Gamma function as
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}
$$

Comment: and you can use L`Hopital in $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2e^{2ax}a}$, 
having like this $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2e^{2ax}a} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{4e^{2ax}a^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{8e^{2ax}a^3} = 0$ 
and apply the same with $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{2e^{2ax}a^2} $

Answer (score 0):

For such integrals it is useful to find the substitution that will make it similar to Gamma function definition:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2\exp\{-2ax\}dx = \frac{1}{(2a)^3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(2ax)^2\exp\{-2ax\} d(2ax) $$
Use the following substitution: $t=-2ax$
if $a > 0$:
$$=\frac{1}{(2a)^3}\int_0^{+\infty}t^2\exp\{-t\}dt = \frac{\Gamma(3)}{(2a)^3} = \frac{2}{8a^3} = \frac{1}{4a^3}$$
if $a<0$:
$$=\frac{1}{(2a)^3}\int_{0}^{-\infty}t^2\exp\{-t\}dt \to \infty$$
if $a=0$:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2dx \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Using L’Hospital Rule, we have
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} x e^{-2 a x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{e^{2 a x}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2 a e^{2 a x}}=0
$$
and
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} x^2 e^{-2 a x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2}{e^{2 a x}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 x}{2 a e^{2 a x}}=0
$$
Therefore via integration by parts twice, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-2 a x} d x 
= & -\frac{1}{2 a} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 d\left(e^{-2 a x}\right) \\
= & -\frac{1}{2 a}\left[x^2 e^{-2 a x}\right]_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} x e^{-2 a x} d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{2 a^2} \int_0^{\infty} x d\left(e^{-2 a x}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2 a^2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2 a x} d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{4 a^3}\left[e^{-2 a x}\right]_0^{\infty}\\=&\frac{1}{4 a^3}
\end{aligned}
$$